# Arduino variable going blank after the first pass

Tags: c, arduino

I have an [Arduino sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) that takes a timet and when that timet is equal to the current time it sets the new timet to timet + 2.

For example:

```
 char* convert(char* x, String y)
 {
     int hour;
     int minute;

     sscanf(x, "%d:%d", &hour, &minute);

     char buf[6];

     if (y == "6")
     {
         if (hour > 17)
         {
             hour = (hour+6)%24;
             snprintf(buf, 10, "%d:%d", hour, minute );
         }
         else
             if (hour < 18)
             {
                 //hour = hour + 6;
                 minute = (minute + 2);
                 snprintf(buf, 10, "%d:%d", hour, minute);
             }
     }

     if (y == "12")
     {
         if (hour > 11)
         {
             hour = (hour+12)%24;
             snprintf(buf, 10, "%d:%d", hour, minute );
         }
         else
             if (hour < 12)
             {
                   hour = hour + 12;
                   snprintf(buf, 10, "%d:%d", hour, minute);
             }
     }

     if (y == "24")
     {
         hour = (hour+24)%24;
         snprintf(buf, 10, "%d:%d", hour, minute );
     }
     return buf;
}
```

The sketch starts for example at 1:00am. timet is set to 1:02, at system time 1:02 timet is equal to the system time.

My loops looks like this:

```
if (timet == currenttime)
{
    timet = convert(timet)
}
```

Whenever I check the value of timet it should equal 1:04, however I get the correct value at the first run after the execution of convert, however every time after that my timet value is blank.

I tried changing the code instead of using the if loop. I only run the convert function when I send for example t through the serial monitor. This works fine and outputs the correct timet after the execution of the convert function,  So I figured the problem is in the if loop...

Any ideas?

Comment: You modified the pointer, not the pointed value!!!!

Comment: So what am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: You can't return pointers to local variables.  You can't compare strings with ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (timet == currenttime){
   timet = convert(timet)
}
```

This is a bad idea.  Either timet stores something in pre-converted format comparable to currenttime or it stores it in post-converted format.

Since you are comparing timet to currenttime, they should be of the same type and format, and be something that can legitimately be compared by the '==' operator.

Probably you want to store timet internally in a numeric format (or whatever you get raw time readings from the runtime in), and convert as you pass it to an output function, or convert to a string format variable (not called timet, but something else!) in preparation for output.

Answer (score 1):

looks dodgy...

passing a pointer?

sure you don't mean *x = *x + 2

Comment: I updated my actual convert function, it takes the time that timet is set to and the interval which is 6 12 or 24.  the inputs are for example 23:0, and 6, the function splits the 23:0 and adds 6 12 or 24 to the 23.  and returns the number after the conversion for example if the input is 23:0 and 6 the output should be 5:0, which is what I get after my first print, but everything after is blank

Answer (score 0):

> instead of using the if loop

Umm, what loop? There's no such thing as an "if loop". That will run exactly once.

Comment: yea it is suppose to run exactly once the convert should only happen when timet is equal to the system time which happens, however the value I get from that convert only prints once anytime after that it is blank.

Comment: but if i don't use the if loop to to execute the convert function, and call it from the serial monitor it works fine.

Comment: You keep saying if loop. There's no such thing as an if loop. You need to post more code.

Comment: Then why do you expect it to keep happening if it's not in a loop?

Comment: I don't expect the assignation of timet = convert(x,y) to keep happening i expect timet to print out the new value of the timet =convert(x,y) everytime void loop executes which it should, because when time is equal to the set time timet is assigned the new value which should be stored on the next iteration of the void loop, correct?

Comment: @Falmarri - arduino sketches generally consist of a startup function and then a loop body function that is called repeatedly by a hidden program skeleton.  There's no user-written main() function as in an ordinary C/C++ program.  The code in question is presumably in the loop function.